# How to suppress DISPPARAMS warnings in msbuild?

Tags: c#, .net, com, msbuild, csc

I have bunch of COM dependencies and my build script emits tons of following warnings:

> c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   : warning : The type library importer
>   could not convert the signature for
>   the member 'DISPPARAMS.rgvarg'.
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   : warning : The type library importer
>   could not convert the signature for
>   the member
>   'DISPPARAMS.rgdispidNamedArgs'.

This is really annoying. How may I suppress them?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) keyword to disable specific warnings.

Comment: The `#pragma` directive only applies to compiler warnings, but it does not work with the warnings from the Type Library Importer.

Comment: `msbuild` warnings (MSB...) in genegal cannot be turned off this way.